# Hide div element using python in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a div element on ticket.html as
`<div class="rgrp" style="visibility:hidden">....<\div>`

So on page /ticket is the form which on submitted redirect to same page as /ticket#

````
@app.route('/ticket', methods=[POST]
def ticket_display() :
     #now here I want to set visibility visible of that div class```
````

Comment: For JavaScript there is query selector, but it is python that too using flask. So can anyone please help to access and set visibility of that div element

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template for ticket.html you could put something like this:

```
<div class="rgrp" style="visibility:{{ visibility }}">....<\div>
```

Then when you're calling your render template, you can do something like this:

```
return render_template('ticket.html', visibility="hidden" )
```

If you need to make it visible later, just change the value of the visibility variable you're passing into the render_template function.